# Should I use Nautilus GIR and if so, where is the documentation?

Tags: python-3.x, gobject, file-browser, nautilus, gobject-introspection

I'm writing a Python3/GObject based application which will use a number of file browser-like widgets. Is the best move to write these from scratch or to use GObject Introspection with Nautilus, and if so where can I find or how can I generate the documentation?

All I have been able to find for Nautilus API docs are extremely old, actually Nautilus-Extension APIs or snippets in others' code.

**Edit:** it seems as though the GIR bindings for Nautilus are in fact for the extension API and that thorough bindings, like we have with Gtk itself, aren't there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer the question of whether you should use Nautilus…  you might want to ask on the [Nautilus mailing list](https://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/nautilus-list) or IRC channel (#nautilus on irc.gnome.org).

Documentation for GObject Introspection is a work in progress, but you can use `g-ir-doc-tool` to generate Mallard files, then use `yelp` to view them (or `yelp-build` to turn them into HTML).  There is some documentation of the process at https://live.gnome.org/GObjectIntrospection/Doctools